# Xubuntu Internet Connection Drops

Tags: wireless, networking, xubuntu, thinkpad, intel-wireless

My problem is a little weird. My internet drops when I download too much data. For example when I download large files. If I just brows it will take a couple of hours to drop. When connection drops the icon still shows that I am connected but no website responds and everything times out. I can do `ifconfig wlan0 down` and then `ifconfig wlan0 up` and then on my taskbar click wireless icon and reconnect to fix this. (just reconnecting without `ifconfig` won't help) but then it will drop sooner than before. If I reboot it will again take a while to disconnect. lcpci for wireless card is as follows:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
```

I read many posts about this issue but nothing helped so far. I had the same problem on my previous laptop with ubuntu and that one was way worse and I never managed to fix it. Any help will be very much appreciated.

**EDIT** : I have installed the driver again but not luck. I forgot how to check which driver it is running. lspci -k does not output the driver specs!

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this in Xubuntu before, its down to the power management. Open a terminal and run the following:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

and see if the issue occurs again while downloading

Comment: I used to get fatal error when launching this command but when I ran it now it was fine. I'll update if Internet dropped again.

Comment: Doesn't this command just turn off the wireless card?

Comment: nope, it turns a value off